# <input/> Text input in Angular-UI accordion heading bootstrap inline edit

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, accordion, angular-ui

I am trying to insert an input in the header of Angular-UI's accordion, but the accordion messes up when the input is shown. I think it might be because I hide the actual heading text so the height of the header changes and the accordion messes up. Ideally, I would like to keep the height dynamic (responsive point-of-view), but a fixed height will do as well.

When the edit button is clicked, I want to show an input field in the header so the user can update the text (saving, or binding the value is not a concern.. just want to show the input field correctly).

I have a demo of what I am wanting using a table, and I would like to replicate that functionality into the accordion header.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr id="th-row">
        <th>Name</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">Actions</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <span ng-show="!edit" ng-model="personName">John Smith</span>

          <div ng-show="edit" class="col-xs-12">
            <input type="text" ng-model="personName" ng-required="true" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Person Name">
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <button ng-show="!edit" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" ng-click="edit = true">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>
          </button>
          <button ng-show="edit" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" ng-click="edit = false">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now my accordion code:

```
<accordion-group>
    <accordion-heading>
      <span ng-show="!edit1" ng-model="headingName">Header with Button group</span>
      <div ng-show="edit1" class="col-xs-12">
        <input type="text" ng-model="headingName" ng-required="true" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Heading Name">
      </div>

      <div class="pull-right">
        <button ng-show="!edit1" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" ng-click="edit1 = true; $event.stopPropagation();"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></button>
        <button ng-show="edit1" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" ng-click="edit1 = false; $event.stopPropagation();"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></button>
      </div>
    </accordion-heading>
    This is just some content to illustrate fancy headings.
</accordion-group>
```

Here is a [**Plunker Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/J8n0acMLvWq3XgbLAHLv?p=preview)